# What plane is shown here in the movie Rampage?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, bomber, stealth

I'm not sure if its a real life airplane, but I feel like I have seen it somewhere:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It looks similiar to the F-117 Nighthawk, pictured below, but it is definitely not this:

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty stupid way of using a stealth bomber, ouch.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Funny thing is they'd probably use a B-52 for an operation like that, but few would recognize it, and they fly too high for dramatic shots like this. I noted the movie *Cloverfield* also used a B-2 for dramatic effect

Comment: @Machavity Granted, the B-2 with its 50,000 ft service ceiling doesn't exactly fly low, either.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, why would you say so? In the movie they are attempting to drop bombs on 3 very large animals and want to avoid being seen?

Comment: @KSplitX: Because the purpose of the B-2 is stealth, and they are flying around low and slow in broad daylight. If they want to avoid being seen, they are doing almost everything wrong that they could possibly do wrong. I mean, the guy in the third screenshot is clearly looking directly at the bomber: not being seen 100% FAIL. The underside of the plane is painted black to be hard to see against the night sky, it is easy to spot against the blue day sky. It is designed to fly very high outside of normal visual range.

Comment: @JörgWMittag it's actually black (or rather a very dark grey) mostly because that's the colour they ended up with when designing the radar absorbent paint. They just didn't bother adding white pigment to turn it air force grey like they did with the F-22 and now F-35. That it makes the B-2 harder to see at night is a bonus, not the original intent.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Northrup Grumman B2 Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_B-2_Spirit) stealth bomber.[image]

Comment: This answer would be improved by showing the B2 from similar angles to the pictures above

Comment: @Richard Did you look at the OP's third picture?

Comment: I did, but they've shown it from various angles.